# sql db2 - how to add/create rows with a 'select'

Tags: select, db2, row, dql

my query pulls data like this:

```
BSYY  CCF
2001  .5
2003  .8
2007  .9
```

I'd like to create values '0' for the years where CCF value doesn't exist so it would look like:

```
BSYY  CCF
2001  .5
2002  0
2003  .8
2004  0
2005  0
2006  0
2007  .9
```

The problem is, I am not given authority of 'create' or 'insert'... Is there a way to do it without creating a temp table?

Comment: How large is the range of years that you need?

Comment: @mustaccio it's from 2001 to 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly do this with SQL, especially if you have a table that can provide all years.  Here is an example showing how to do it by generating a table:

```
with
   t (bsyy, ccf) as (values (2001, 0.5),(2003,0.8),(2007,0.9))
  ,y (year) as (values (2000),(2001),(2002),(2003),(2004),
                       (2005),(2006),(2007),(2008),(2009))
select
   y.year
  ,coalesce(t.ccf,0.0) as ccf
from
   y
   left outer join t on y.year = t.bsyy
order by
   y.year;
```

You would replace the `t` common table expression with your actual source table.  For example, if you have a table called `tab1` that has columns `bsyy` and `ccf`, the query would be:

```
with
   y (year) as (values (2000),(2001),(2002),(2003),(2004),
                       (2005),(2006),(2007),(2008),(2009))
select
   y.year
  ,coalesce(t.ccf,0.0) as ccf
from
   y
   left outer join tab1 t 
      on y.year = t.bsyy
order by
   y.year;
```

Instead of hard-coding the values for the `y` common table expression, you could use a recursive expression to generate those values for you.

However, why force the DBMS to do this?  Why not just do it at the application level?

Comment: thanks! that worked, however, I have a problem.. my table actually has 5 columns (BSYY, CCF, CLIENT_TYPE, PRODUCT_SEGMENT, PRODUCT_COUNT) and it will take forever to manually type in ALL values into table 't' as above in your answer. I should have stated this in the original question, sorry. Would there be a way to do this without having to put in each resulting value of table 't'?

Comment: I'm forcing DBMS to do this instead of application because there are about 40 tables of this type and I was wondering if, instead of organizing the data in Excel, I can just pull the data this way so that I won't have to edit it in Excel. I could make a template with if&vlookup statements in Excel but I was wondering if I can pull the data in this formate straight from the DBMS.. save one step!

Comment: @user2810030 As I mention in my answer, you can replace the `t` common table expression with the actual table you are querying.  In my code above, `t` is just there to hold example data.

Comment: sorry what would be the syntax for the first line if not specifying the values?

Comment: @user2810030 Updated the answer with a second example.